# PHP: Can't use function return value in context - error

Tags: php, arrays, return

I'm not too sure what exactly it is I'm doing wrong, and I did check with other questions, and all I kind of inferred was that returning (something called "empty") only supports variables, although that didn't really change anything.

I am getting a very strange error in my code when I run it, and can't make head or tails of it.

```
Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in /home/shortcu1/public_html/projects/friendcodes/newUser.php on line 103
```

This is the main function that's being called. (in a file called **newUser.php**)

```
function isBumping($forumid, $username, $premium){
    if($premium == 'true'){
        $file = file_get_contents('plist.txt'); // This is the file I'm testing on
        echo 'Running code as premium<br>';
    } else {
        $file = file_get_contents('list.txt');
    }
    $forumid = $forumid.':'.$username;
    $posts = explode(' ', $file);
    $posts ($info, $bump) = array_filter($posts, function($item) use ($forumid, $posts){
        // This will check for matching forum ID
        if(strpos($item, $forumid) !== true){
            $pos = strpos($item, ':Day-');
            $pos = $pos + 5;
            $day = (int) substr($item, $pos, 1); // Converts the stored date to a numerical value. remember 1 = monday, 7 = sunday
            $today = date('N');
            $bump = false;
            if(($day+3) % 7 > $today){
                // Old enough to re-bump
                return array ($item, $bump);
            } else {
                // Too recent to re-bump
                $bump = true;
                return array ($item, $bump);
            }
        }
    });
    print_r($posts[1]);
    echo '<br>';
    print_r($posts[2]);

}
```

It is being run through the file **test.php**:

```
include('newUser.php');
isBumping(1, 'Spitfire', 'true')
```

The file called **plist.txt** is as follows:

> 1:Spitfire:Day-4:8JX-UKR8:8JX-UKR8:Spirit:90
>   1:Spitfire:Day-4:8JX-UKR8:8JX-UKR8:Spirit:90
>   1:Spitfire:Day-4:8JX-UKR8:8JX-UKR8:Spirit:90
>   1:Spitfire:Day-4:8JX-UKR8:8JX-UKR8:Spirit:90

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

`$posts ($info, $bump) =`

to

`$posts =`

Answer (score 2):

`array_filter` returns the array having all non empty element of the array.

You cann't use `$post($a, $b)` for this
try changing to to a variable

like simply **$post**.